# The quality of being apologetic

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, emotions

What is the word/noun for 'the quality of being apologetic'?

*[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/apologetic)* definition of *apologetic*:

> *adjective* 
> Expressing or showing regretful acknowledgement of an offence or failure. 
> *‘she was very apologetic about the whole incident’*

Is it *apologism*? *Apologeticness*? Anything else?

An example of my desired word is:

> The prevalent tones in this text area: sadness, anger and ______"

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by an example sentence in which a blank replaces the intended word. The sentence should provide some context.

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of the words you are suggesting?

Comment: Considering that I'm asking a question on StackExchange, that inference seems reasonable

Comment: _Apologeticness_ is not useful and sounds off, even one can find [usages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apologeticness%22&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&biw=1536&bih=688&tbm=bks&ei=Kie8YvChC5H_lwT2vo2IDQ&ved=0ahUKEwjw3u3kt9L4AhWR_4UKHXZfA9EQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22apologeticness%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQhAZY9ghgjRFoAHAAeACAAW2IAbICkgEDMS4ymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books). A more common and appropriate word is _remorse_ which is the feeling of regret.

Comment: I rather like _apologeticalistically_. It has a certain ring. A full ring of Treble Bob Major, in fact.

Comment: The example sentence may lack a verb but its use is clear. Leave open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a good possibility is the word ***remorse***:

- *"The prevalent tones in this text area: sadness, anger and remorse."*

Then there is ***repentance***:

- *"The prevalent tones in this text area: sadness, anger and repentance."*

Another possibility is ***contrition***:

- *"The prevalent tones in this text area: sadness, anger and contrition."*

Comment: Thanks; although they slightly differ, it sounds so much better.

Answer (score 1):

Neither '*apologism*' nor '*apologeticness*' is part of either lexico's or dictionary.com's word list.

However, on Wiktionary the word [apologeticness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apologeticness) has the exact meaning you're looking for:

> The quality of being apologetic.

Theoretically this should be alright to use and easily understood, as the '-ness' suffix is appended to indicate 'the quality of being' the adjective that precedes it.

And for completeness' sake, 'apologism' [there](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apologism) is defined as

> A defence or excuse; a speech or written answer made to justify someone.

Comment: Good answer. Also, you can suggest a common alternative(s) as _apologeticness_ is not really useful and sounds off.

Comment: *Apologism* is whence apologetics derive. The dichotomy between *apology* = "Reasons for belief" and *apology* = "Expression of remorse" is intriguing.